# Multiple assignments from a python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, variable-assignment

Is it possible to make this line of code valid?

```
description, content, state, city, datetime = makeTupleRightOrder(dictionary)
```

this makeTupleRightOrder would get the 'parameters' from the left side of the assignment, convert their names to strings and build a list getting their values from the dictionary.

Comment: rewrite it as `map(lambda x:dictionary[x],[description, content, state, city, datetime])`

Comment: `locals().update(dictionary)` accomplishes your end goal of converting a dictionary to variable names.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski The contents of `locals()` should not be modified.

Comment: @JoshLee:  Why not?  That is what the OP is attempting with his code.

Comment: @Abhijit it's not working, python throws a name error (as suspected)

Comment: @StevenRumbalski: Why not?  Because it does not work.  See the documentation of `locals()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. The function has no idea what's on the left side of the assignment, and even if it did, the variables might well have names different from the keys.

Answer (score 2):

kindall is right. For the general case, you can't do this. What you *can* do is sort the keys alphabetically, and **always** make sure that the variables you are unpacking the dict to are in the correct (alphabetic order) in terms of the keys:

```
city, content, datetime, description, state = [dictionary[k] for k in sorted(dictionary)]
```

(This example assumes the dictionary keys are named identically to the variables you are unpacking them to).

**NOTE**

If you are running into situations where you are forced to do this, I would consider designing your code differently. Your implementation is probably flawed.

Comment: This is definitely going too far, but if you made the variables on the left side into smart objects that 'knew' about eachother, you could have them exchange data until they had the right values. It would be cool, but utterly pointless.

Comment: @Joel: Even if the objects on the left side are somehow "smart", it doesn't matter because they will be totally different objects after the assignment. (It's not possible to override assignment in Python.)